# Fluentd with HEC on Centos

Tags: logging, splunk, fluentd

I am trying to configure fluentd using td-agent steps with HEC for logging on centos, i am able to do complete installation with no issues, but when trying to insert HEC Stanza in tdagent.conf and then restarting the service, fluentd is not starting and coming in failed state.

i have tried various solutions, but with no luck. (Tracked fluentd GitHub issues as well)

my conf file - /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf

HEC block -

```
<match **>
  @type splunk_hec
  hec_host http-wwww.example.com
  hec_port XXX
  hec_token 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
</match>
```

After Restarting service status is falied with following warning ( Checked with sudo tail -f /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log )

```
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.2.0'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '1.3.1'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-splunk-hec' version '1.2.1'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.2'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '1.1.0'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td-monitoring' version '0.2.4'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '1.2.4'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.10.2'
2020-04-27 06:37:37 +0000 [warn]: [output_td] Use different plugin for secondary. Check the plugin works with primary like secondary_file primary="Fluent::Plugin::TreasureDataLogOutput" secondary="Fluent::Plugin::FileOutput"
```

I have installed fluentd-HEC plugin using **sudo td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-splunk-hec -v 1.2.1**

On removing HEC block from td-agent.conf file fluentd runs normally.